# An internal error occurred during: "Check license status". ECLIPSE_HOME is undefined

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, initialization, startup

I have eclipse Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0) for java.

On every startup eclipse shows this error.

It is not creating any problem.

But still bugging me.

I have changed workspace and still the same.

Installed pluggin:

1. Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.19
2. Maven Integration for Eclipse (Luna and Newer) 1.5

Comment: How did you install this?

Comment: Show us the complete stacktrace.  (Check the log file).  When I Googled this, the other hits all talked about a plugin for Angular development called CodeMix. (For example: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1108212/) Are you using that?  Were you using it previously?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't do any sort of license check, this must be some plug-in you have installed. I checked and that message does not occur anywhere in the main Eclipse code.

Answer (score 0):

That's **not Eclipse**, but a [**known issue of CodeMix**](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/codemix-and-eclipse/) or another Genuitec plugin you have installed.

In contrast to CodeMix, [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) is free and open source (so no license checking at all), providing also support for JavaScript, TypeScript and other languages and frameworks via VS Code language servers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

Credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/users/14262893/tom-k%c3%a1roly

My file was at "c:\Program Files\eclipse\configuration\config.ini"
The path may vary as per your eclipse installation.

```
eclipse.home=c:\Program Files\eclipse\
```

I added this line in the "config.ini" file and no more prompting.